# Updating database according to check-boxes checked

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I've the following table layout in my database with some data.
[image: Table Layout in database]

I'm taking input by check-boxes so user can select all applicable accident road conditions and it to database. I would say it is okay if you're adding a new record you just loop through the checkboexs checked and insert them in DB

[image: First screen user checked some road conditions]

The first information is now saved in the database, now user decided to change the road conditions for any reasons user came back and change it the to the following.

[image: User change the checkboexs values]

Now my question, how should I update my table. The first thing that came into my mind was to delete the record that were already there and insert the new one's.

My real issue here is, assume user have choose the 3 items before but changed it two or one then how would i delete the those are not checked you know what I'm saying. Below is some code snippets that I've been trying.

```
$accidentRoadConditions = AccidentRoadConditions::findAccidentRoadConditions($acc_det_id);
$wc_array = [];

while ($roadConditions = $accidentRoadConditions ->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
    $wc_array[] = $roadConditions ->rc_id;
}
```

Above I'm selecting all the road conditions that is already stored in the database.

```
if (isset($_POST['rta_ad_rc'])) {
    foreach ($_POST['rta_ad_rc'] as $rc_id) {
        //AccidentRoadConditions::save(array(null, $ad_lsid, $rc_id));
        // $tmprory = AccidentRoadConditions::findByADAndRCIds($acc_det_id, $rc_id);
        // if(!$tmprory){
        //  AccidentRoadConditions::save(array(null, $acc_det_id, $rc_id));
        // }
        if(in_array($rc_id, $wc_array)){
            $errors[] =  "in array <br />";
            unset($wc_array[0]);
        }
    }
}
```

So my question is how to update values in database according to what was checked by user and deleting those which were unchecked which were checked before. Getting bit complicated so simply how to update database according to above mention scenario.

Any Idea?

Comment: delete all rows related and insert again is the simple way to make this.

Comment: that's what I thought before as mentioned in the question just wondering if there's any other way otherwise I've that option available. thanks anyways @ThiagoFrança

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to do the following

- Store the selected checks in an array
- Check in the database if any of those are already saved or not
- if yes, skipped them otherwise add them into an array

  $old_rc_array = [];
  $new_rc_array = [];

  while ($roadConditions = $accidentRoadConditions->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
      $old_rc_array[] = $roadConditions->rc_id;
  }

  if (isset($_POST['rta_ad_rc'])) {

  foreach ($_POST['rta_ad_rc'] as $rc_id) {

  ```
  if(in_array($rc_id, $old_rc_array)){
      unset($old_rc_array[array_search($rc_id, $old_rc_array)]);
  }else{
      $new_rc_array[] = $rc_id;
  }
  ```

  }
  }

  foreach ($old_rc_array as $rc_to_delete) {
      AccidentRoadConditions::deleteByADIdAndRCId($hidden_acc_det_id, $rc_to_delete);
  }

  foreach ($new_rc_array as $rc_to_insert) {
      AccidentRoadConditions::save(array(null, $hidden_acc_det_id, $rc_to_insert));
  }

Comment: Thank you @Sharif I'll sort the formatting out myself

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you should do.

- Create composite unique constraint on ad_id and rc_id
- Delete all the rows not in the selected checkbox ids.
- Try to insert all the rows but user INSERT IGNORE. This will insert the record if it does not exist or it will just ignore it. As you are using some framework see how you can do that.
  If you can not then just wrap it using try/catch and ignore if the error is related to constraint violation.

This way You don't need to check if the values exist and also there will not be any unnecessary inserts.

Comment: this is what i'm doing with that code `$tmprory = AccidentRoadConditions::findByADAndRCIds($acc_det_id, $rc_id); 
        if(!$tmprory){
        AccidentRoadConditions::save(array(null, $acc_det_id, $rc_id));
        // }`

Comment: Yes, but You are first checking if the record exist and then inserting. You can avoid that by adding composite unique constraint. So even if you try DB won't let you do it.

Comment: the code above check if the record already there in the database if no insert new otherwise do nothing

Comment: everything under try catch block I've dumped the full code here

Comment: yes, I get that but You are making two db calls first to check if the row exist and second you insert. If you have unique constraint you don't need to check if the row exist DB will throw error if it does and you can just ignore the error.

Comment: oh yes let me try that